# Copying an array of dynamic ranges, starting from searched cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large sheet of data:

[Updated Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSNcb.png)

where i need to copy only a speacific part of this data to another worksheet:

[image: worksheet]

The data i need to copy is always 4 cells wide however can be at any row and column. The first column cell at the top will allways be the same text value and i need to copy then from that found cell, 4 cells across to the right and then down to the cells are empty. All subsequent ranges after the first will use the same columns have several empty cells bother above and below each range needed. The macro will be run using a "button" so doesn't need to be checking the value of the cell all the time. The images are simplified versions of the data but are very accurate. 0 is used to show data surrounding range, HELLO is the data inside the range and INT_EXT_DOOR is my searched for cell value which can be in any column between data sets but will be the same inside each data set. The first range always starts at row 2.

Each range has to be numbered, defined by another worksheets cell value. For example, if my cell value is 1 i need it to copy range 1, if my value is 2 copy range 2 ect.

I have been trying to no luck to get anything that works like needed and would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try something on your own? Maybe we could better understand what you really want to accomplish. Can you edit your question and add, at least, two pictures (if not something editable) able to present your initial situation, the searching rule and how the result must look. You said something about copying to another worksheet. Such a worksheet is big... Where, in this worksheet, the range/ranges of the first one to be copied?

Comment: A piece of code from you have been trying, maybe will make us understand more then your explanation in words...

Comment: Just to repeat what I understand: you have a block of data 4 * X cells of size (X = # of rows). Cell(1,1) of this block in your example always has "INT_EXT_DOOR", but this cell can be in any column in a given row. From there you have to loop down the rows until you find the first empty cell. Based on a cell in another sheet you need to select the nth block in a given sheet. In each row there is max. one "Cell(1,1). If this is correct I can start thinking about a piece of code for your task.

Comment: Yes Ultra Junkie, that is all correct. Cell(1,1) only appears at 1,1 in each block, only ever not under an empty cell for the first instance of the block range.

Comment: Showing us what you have tried will help in both understanding your problem, and crafting a solution. It would seem like `Range.Find` method would be a good place to start.

Comment: So, your piece of cod must have to input elements: "INT_EXT_DOOR" and 'block number'. Is that correct? Then, "INT_EXT_DOOR" will always be on the same column. Is that correct, too? Then, I do not understand what "4 cells across to the right " means. Your example show us two columns... And the rows, also, are five. What does it should mean?

Comment: FaneDuru, in the example i have hidden columns B & C as this is what it will look like in my work, i want to see coulms 1 and 4 but have access to 1-4. The number of rows means nothing. each range can be anything from 2-300 rows. the space between each data range is vairable also. the "4 cells across to the right" was my my way of explaining that each data range is 4 cells wide. the data shown in the image can be at any row and any column. the only 2 things that stay the same are cell(1,1) value and that the data range is 4 cells wide.

Comment: OK. In some minutes I will post an answer...

Comment: okay, thanks. The reason i haven't posted my code is simply because it doesn't work in any capasity i need it to. i figured it would be easier to explain my problem to people who would have the know how to prehaps solve it and not distract with my crap attempt at it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the next function, please:

```
Private Function testReturnBlock(strBlock As String, blkNo As Long)
   Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, searchC As Range
   Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet to be processed
    Set ws = Worksheets("Return") 'use here your sheet where the data will be returned

    Set searchC = sh.UsedRange.Find(strBlock)
    If searchC Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No such a field in the worksheet...": Exit Function

    lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, searchC.Column).End(xlUp).row
    'The following part works well only if the blocks are separated by empty rows, as you said it is your sheet data case...
    Set rng = sh.Range(searchC, sh.Cells(LastRow, searchC.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
     ws.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Areas(blkNo).Rows.Count, 4).Value = rng.Areas(blkNo).Resize(, 4).Value
End Function
```

The above function should be called like this:

```
Sub testRetBlock()
   testReturnBlock "INT_EXT_DOOR", 2
End Sub
```

But in order to see that the correct range has been returned, you must adapt them in a way (in your test sheet), do differentiate. I mean the second one to contain "HELLO1" (at least on its first row), the following "HELLO2" and so on...

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: So, does it do what you asked in your question?

Comment: nice solution, shorter than mine :-). But I recently learned that you need to be careful with "usedRange" as it is affected by empty cells and in some cases returns false results

Comment: @Ultra Junkie: Not really, for such a case. It may return false results if you try to define its last row, last column. If you will write some lines down or to the right and then delete them, then UsedRange will include them. I you will format some new rows thew will also be included. But in the above code case, using it is the simplest, shortest and without any risc for `Find` function to properly return inside it. It is not influenced by 'empty rows' in terms of missing something.

Comment: For your soluton, in my work it is copying the 4 columns to the right of "INT_EXT_DOOR". the example it works fine however, do you have any idea what may cause it to be 1 collumn off?

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: Can you update your test pictures with ones reflecting your real situation? The relevant part...

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: One column off of what? Of the four columns to be returned? Even if so, if I do not see your sheet with real data, I cannot have an opinion on the issue...

Comment: I'm unable to shre the real data due to sensitivity however i'm now aware as to why it's going wrong. Imagine a row of data (marked as "HELLO") is missing mid way through the range. Column 1 always has data however columns 2-4 can be empty cells. I'm about to add in a new image showing my Data a little better for you.

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: So, the column of the searched string does not have such empty cells. Is it correct? If yes, I will adapt the code to return correctly...

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: Test the updated code, please and let me know how it behaves. I will live the office in some minutes. If no answer until I live, I can look to your questions only after two, three hours...

Comment: yes the searched string column is always full throughout the range. I'll try it now.

Comment: @Nathan Barrow:  Then, it should work. The code needs only some parte of the range to be split in arrays. I found another way to build the whole range to be retrieved...

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: What I would like to here, is a statement that you understood the code. Not right now... :)

Comment: i'm already onto googling all the different bits you've used that i didn't know of and what they're doing. i have it wokring in my work now but i'll for sure play around with it so i understand what's going on and so i can create it again myslef if needed at a later date.

Comment: @Nathan Barrow: Some hints: Basically, the big hint/trick is the fact that using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` for a discontinue range, it splits it on such areas. Try `Debug.Print rng.Address`. You will be able to see the addresses of each area. Then, `Resize` should be easy to understand. It makes what its 'name' suggests' in terms of adding rows and columns. So, having the areas, you can extend them as you need...

Answer (score 0):

Try this routine if it does what you need. otherwise it should be a good start for adding whatever you need on top.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyBlock()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsSelect As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lBlockNo As Long
    Dim strCellID As String
    Dim lBlock As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lBlockRow As Long
    Dim lBlockCol As Long
    Dim searchRange As Excel.Range
    Dim bRange As Excel.Range
    Dim cRange As Excel.Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

' set the worksheet objects
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Dest")
    Set wsSelect = wb.Sheets("Select")      ' here you select which block you want to copy

' Identifier String
    strCellID = "INT_EXT_DOOR"

' Which block to show. We assume that the number is in cell A1, but could be anywhere else
    lBlockNo = wsSelect.Range("A1")

    lRow = 1

' Find block with lBlockNo
    For lBlock = 1 To lBlockNo

' Search the identifier string in current row
        Do
            lRow = lRow + 1
            Set searchRange = wsSource.Rows(lRow)
            Set bRange = searchRange.Find(strCellID, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Loop While (bRange Is Nothing)

    Next lBlock

    lBlockRow = bRange.Row
    lBlockCol = bRange.Column

' Search the first with empty cell
    Do
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop While wsSource.Cells(lRow, lBlockCol) <> ""

' Copy the range found into the destination sheet
    Range(Cells(lBlockRow, lBlockCol), Cells(lRow - 1, lBlockCol + 3)).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")

' Note the block copied
    wsDest.Cells(1, 6) = "Block No:"
    wsDest.Cells(1, 8) = lBlockNo

' Clean up (not absolutely necessary, but good practice)
    Set searchRange = Nothing
    Set bRange = Nothing
    Set cRange = Nothing
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    Set wsDest = Nothing
    Set wsSelect = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need more help